# Sheetname recognizing script fails after manually duplicating sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet named `First` containing the following in cell A1 (see below). 
After I **manually** duplicate `First` during google spreadsheet development, I want the duplicated cell A1 value to be `Second Round`, but even after a refresh of the manually duplicated and **renamed** sheet `Second`, the value of cell A1 is `Copy of First Round`.

Can I alter the script or something to get my desired result, `Second Round`?

A1: =SHEETNAME()&" Round"

Script to access sheetname:

```
function sheetname() {
   var sheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
          return sheetname;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be some kind of trigger to cause the function to run.  A custom function in a cell in the spreadsheet will only run if a cell in the range inside the () changes.  You COULD set this to be a large range, as long as you don't include the cell the formula is in as this causes an error.  Then you will get an update when a cell changes.  Unfortunately this does not include the reference to the sheet name changing, such as Sheet1 in `=getSheetname(Sheet1!B1:Z)`

There are Triggers which happen in scripts, and can cause a given function to run.  The onChange trigger has to be manually applied to a function, meaning in the script editor you set it under *Edit->Current project's triggers.*  The probnlem, however, is that it will not update any cells unless you have code in the function to change specific cells.  So you would not have a function in the cell, but this in the script editor, with A13 set to the cell where you want the sheet name.  Once that is in and the Trigger is set, changing the sheet name will change the cell value.

```
function getSheetname() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetname = ss.getName();
  ss.getRange('A13').setValue(sheetname);
  return;
}
```

Comment: I think your answers are like workarounds for something not yet practical. For my app, what I need is the name of the current sheet and the name of the previous sheet where the sheets are named in order: First, Second, ... ,Sixth. With so few I think I'll just **manually** create a pair of cells in sheets Second, ... , Sixth that contain it's own name and its predecessor's name. I guess the user could resequence the tabs of the sheets, but presumably would not rename the sheets.